# Trying to make a custom multi select search component with mat-select-list in overlay

Tags: angular, angular-material, overlay, angular8, angular-cdk

I'm trying to make a custom Angular Material multiSelect filterable component, such as this one : 
[image]

I made a multi-select-search.component with this code :

```
export interface MultiSelectSearchOption {
    label: string;
    value: any;
}

export interface MultiSelectOverlayData {
    options: MultiSelectSearchOption[];
}

export const MULTI_SELECT_OVERLAY_DATA = new InjectionToken<
    MultiSelectOverlayData
>('MULTI_SELECT_OVERLAY_DATA');



//TEXT INPUT COMPONENTS
@Component({
    selector: 'multiSelectSearch',
    templateUrl: 'multiSelectSearch.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./multiSelectSearch.component.scss'],
})
export class MultiSelectSearchComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @Input() list: any[] = [];
    @Input() selection: any;
    /**
     * @param filterKey
     * @description the key of the object to filter out with the text input
     */
    @Input() filterKey: string;
    /**
     * @param labelKey
     * @description the key of the object to be used as label of option
     */
    @Input() labelKey: string;
    @Input() placeholder: string;
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<any[]>();
    @ViewChild('input', { static: false }) inputViewRef: ElementRef;
    public search = new FormControl('');
    private listOptions: MultiSelectSearchOption[] = [];
    private overlayRef: OverlayRef;
    constructor(private overlay: Overlay) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        if (!this.list.length || !this.labelKey || !this.filterKey) {
            console.error(
                'Component usage require input of list, labelKey, filterKey component'
            );
            throw new Error();
        } else {
            this.search.valueChanges
                .pipe(debounceTime(1000))
                .subscribe(search => {
                    this.listOptions = (!search.length
                        ? this.list
                        : this.list.filter(e =>
                              e[this.filterKey]
                                  .toString()
                                  .toUpperCase()
                                  .startsWith(search.toUpperCase())
                          )
                    ).map(
                        (e: any): MultiSelectSearchOption => ({
                            label: e[this.labelKey],
                            value: e,
                        })
                    );
                    const tokens = new WeakMap();
                    tokens.set(MULTI_SELECT_OVERLAY_DATA, {
                        options: this.listOptions,
                    });
                    this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({
                        hasBackdrop: false,
                        minWidth: '10vw',
                        minHeight: '10vh',
                        positionStrategy: this.overlay
                            .position()
                            .flexibleConnectedTo(this.inputViewRef)
                            .withPositions([
                                {
                                    offsetX: 0,
                                    offsetY: 0,
                                    originX: 'start',
                                    originY: 'top',
                                    overlayX: 'start',
                                    overlayY: 'top',
                                    panelClass: [],
                                    weight: 1,
                                },
                            ]),
                    });
                    const multiSelectPortal = new ComponentPortal(
                        MultiSelectOverlayComponent,
                        null,
                        tokens
                    );
                    this.overlayRef.attach(multiSelectPortal);
                });
        }
    }
}

// OVERLAY COMPONENT
@Component({
    selector: 'multi-select-overlay',
    template: `
        <mat-card>
            <mat-selection-list #list>
                <mat-list-option
                    *ngFor="let option of listOptions"
                    [value]="option.value"
                    >{{ option.label }}</mat-list-option
                >
            </mat-selection-list>
        </mat-card>
    `,
})
export class MultiSelectOverlayComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('list', { static: false }) list: MatSelectionList;
    public get listOptions() {
        return this.data.options as MultiSelectSearchOption[];
    }
    constructor(
        @Inject(MULTI_SELECT_OVERLAY_DATA)
        private data: MultiSelectOverlayData
    ) {
        console.log('data', data);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.list.selectionChange.pipe(
            //emit value
            tap(x => console.log(x))
        );
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine, but when i try to iterate over my `data.options` element, i get the following error : 
[image]

I don't understand why the component created by the ComponentPortal fail to use ngFor on an Array?

Reproduction

Use StackBlitz to demonstrate what you are trying to do: 
Full error and code here :
https://components-issue-55qrra.stackblitz.io/

Environment

- Angular: 8.1.1
- CDK/Material: 8.0.2
- Browser(s): Chrome
- Operating System Windows,

I put a `console.log` of the `data` object passed, i can see that it is indeed an Array :
[image]

go to stackblitz https://components-issue-55qrra.stackblitz.io/

I

Error msg received (as seen on Stackblitz) : 
`ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this answer from angular material support :

> The root cause of the issue is that the overlay component is being given an injector that does not contain `differs` for `ngFor`. This is because you created the overlay as a component without any parent injector that had these `differs`.
>   In `multi-select-search.component.ts`, when you create the `ComponentPortal`, be sure to include the current injector using a `PortalInjector`:

```
import { PortalInjector } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
...
const tokens = new WeakMap();
tokens.set(MULTI_SELECT_OVERLAY_DATA, {
  options: this.listOptions,
});
const injector = new PortalInjector(this.injector, tokens);

...

const multiSelectPortal = new ComponentPortal(MultiSelectOverlayComponent, null, injector);
```

Hope this can help someone !